# Несколько отчетов в действии перехода к другому отчету

Tags: ssrs

Добрый день, возникла необходимость реализации перехода к другому отчету по условию параметра, реализую переход по имени отчета так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В функции выбора отчета пишу:

`IIF(Parameters!IncludedItemsFilter.Value=2,FirstReport,SecondReport)`

и получаю ошибку с некорректным именем отчета, хотя оба отчета находятся на этом же сервере и доступны.

Поиски в интернетах ни к чему не привели, как реализовать такой "зависимый переход" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для реализиции условного перехода в таблице необходимо разместить элемент `Rectangle` и вложить в него нужное количество `TextBox` (по количеству зависимых переходов), в каждом `TextBox` настроить свой `Action` и `Visibility` в зависимости от первоначального условия.